# Textbox values are not working in pdf using MPDF php

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am working on one website where i want to create pdf from html.My code works but textbox values are not rendering on pdf.I am using mpdf library for this purpose.My code is below.

```
include("../../../MPDF/mpdf.php");
$html=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth','continuous');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../../../MPDF/examples/mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: Try to use an online converter, like this one for exemple: http://simplehtmltopdf.com

Comment: @Superdrac Thanks for message.But i think it's not good idea to use oline pdf for local or https project.

Comment: Yeah it's true, try to install wkhtmltopdf if you are on linux, and wrap it with php !